# Combining words in a string into anagrams using ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, split, group-by

I wanted to make a program in which I would be able to sort and store the characters which are anagrams into individual groups. For ex for the string:

"scream cars for four scar creams" the answer should be:

```
[["scream", "creams"], ["cars", "scar"], ["for"], ["four"]]
```

For the above I used the code:

```
here = self.split()
there = here.group_by { |x| x.downcase.chars.sort}.values
```

And I got the required answer. But when I change the code to:

```
here = self.split()
there = here.group_by { |x| x.downcase.chars.sort}
```

I get the answer:

```
{["a", "c", "e", "m", "r", "s"]=>["scream", "creams"], ["a", "c", "r", "s"]=>["cars", "scar"], ["f", "o", "r"]=>["for"], ["f", "o", "r", "u"]=>["four"]}
```

I would like to know that why it is like this now? I got to the answer using hit-and-trial method.

Comment: You are using group_by which returns a hash
You can see that here http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by.

Comment: @Kranthi I want to know that why does removing "values" change the answer from the required to what I finally got?

Comment: Because you are sorting them based on the characters using #chars.

Comment: First it sort the letters and then it repeatedly checks which word matches that and based on that it groups the words.

Comment: @Rohit because `values` is a method: Returns a new array populated with the values from hsh. ( www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Hash.html#method-i-values ). When you remove it you get whole hash, not array of values.

Comment: @rohit, whenever you get useful info, accept the answers so that you get better answers from community.

Comment: @Kranthi I would, but you need to write it up as an answer first, right?

Comment: Even comments also gives useful info, if a comment gives some useful info to your post then you can click up arrow mark which is at that comment!

Comment: If you find better meaning for your post yourself, you can post  it as well so that its usefull for the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by *Yevgeniy Anfilofyev* , [values](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Hash.html#method-i-values) is a method and hence it

> Returns a new array populated with the values from hash

While, if we remove the method `values` then we get the whole hash and not only the `array` of values.